# "ResultSet is from UPDATE: No Data" received from Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to use a Java application (which I do not have the source code for) to output the results of a call to a stored procedure into a text file.

This file works for other similar stored procedures in the system, but I can't seem to get it to produce anything for my new text file other than this exception:

> ResultSet is from UPDATE: No Data

I've simplified the body of the stored procedure to a simple `select 'Hello World!'` and even that doesn't seem to be able to be written out.

Is there anything I can do within the stored procedure to produce results in a fashion that Java will accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this `java.sql.SQLException`. In my case I was running a query in this way:

```
String query = 
    "-- a classical comment " +
    "select * " +
    "from MYTABLE ";
ResultSet rs = conMain.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()) {
    //do something...
}
```

`rs.next()` throws the exception. The reason is that, due to the **comments**, `query` results to be:

```
"-- a classical comment select * from MYTABLE "
```

hence it's all commented... query is invalid! Many examples could be shown with this mistake (with the comment in the middle of the query etc.).

**Solutions**: add a `\n` at the end of each line of the query or use comments in the `/*...*/` form.

Comment: It was something similar, my query was valid, but returning no results. The exception text mentioning UPDATE is somewhat misleading, but the "no data" part is spot on :)

Answer (score -1):

I selected an older version of the driver an it worked for me.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=13598 (mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.zip)